# The Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider IS registered on the local machine but keep getting this error

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledb, aspxgridview, oledbconnection

I know this question has been asked plenty but I can't find a fix. I am trying to import an excel file and bind it to an aspxgridview. I have installed the AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe redistributable on my local machine, but I keep geeting the "The Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered on the local machine". below is a snippet of code.

```
string connStr = "";
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(fuImportPP.FileName).ToLower();
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/ExcelToGrid/" + fuImportPP.FileName);

            gv = new GridView();

            fuImportPP.SaveAs(path);

            //if (ext.Trim() == ".xls")
            //    //connection string for that file which extantion is .xls  
            //    connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
            //else if (ext.Trim() == ".xlsx")
                connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";

            string query = "SELECT * FROM [GridViewExport$]";

            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);

            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                conn.Open();

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn); 
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            da.Fill(ds);
            gv.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            gv.DataBind();
            phGridViewHolder.Controls.Add(gv);
            conn.Close();
```

Comment: If you install the x64 engine then your code also needs to be compiled as x64, is that the case?

Comment: It appears to be x32, how do I change it in VS 2017?

Comment: Another quick question, how do you accommodate for both xls and xlsx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check the bitness of your office installation 
Since you're using c#, Try and go to Project > Project Properties > Click on the Build Tab > Where it Platform Target > Change it so that for example if you Office Installation is 32 Bit then change it to 32 Bit and if it is 64 Bit then change it to 64 Bit.
 
After that save and try running your project again.

Comment: I made the change as suggested now I get an error "Could not load file or assembly 'MMT_CustomPlugin' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. "

Comment: If you go 64 bit (or 32 bit) then all your referenced assemblies must be of the same bitness.  Perhaps remove the x64 Access engine and install the 32 bit version & go with that, it will probably be simpler.